# Android background task issue

Tags: java, android, service

I am having a background task issue with Service class from Android, Whenever I am starting service from application and return to main menu on my device till then service running properly, but When I will clear all the background application from the recent application list then the service also stops. So how can I manage to avoid such a thing.

Comment: consider posting some code

Answer (score 2):

The `onStartCommand` method on your sub `IntentService` class should return `Service.START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //some code...
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Then the service will keep running in background.

Comment: It is only working on those devices which having OS before marshmallow.

Comment: No it works with higher versions also, Tested it on nexus 5X with Nougat 7.1.1 and it works fine.

Comment: When I tested my application on jellybean OS device then it works fine but When i tested it on marshmallow OS device then it will terminate the application when clear the background application.

Comment: Weird, does your code require some runtime permissions by any chance ?

Comment: Yes, It ask for EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA and RECORD_AUDIO permission at run time.

Comment: So this can be the problem why it's not working for 6+ OS, maybe you are not handling runtime permissions grant well. Because I'm already implemeting like that and it works with no issues

Comment: If you don't mind, Can you please share your permission code?

Answer (score 1):

> When I will clear all the background application from the recent application list then the service also stops

You can use `startForeground()` to declare it to be a foreground service.  A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing" heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

```
 Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: But how can I start the service using startForrground()?